# Node mongo count query items

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pagination

I have a simple GET search. Problem is that when I use some criteria like status or name or email it shows correct results BUT pagination behave like there were no criteria.

For example, there is one user in DB with name John so I search for John and it gives me exactly him as a result. But pagination shows me 10pages and I don't know how to fix it. When I parse `count` it gives me all results not only one,

Here is my controller

```
/**
 * GET /admin/users/:page
 * Find users
 */
exports.findUsers = (req, res, next) => {
  const perPage = 13
  const page = Number(req.params.page) || 1

  var query = {};

  const possibleQueryProps = [{
      "key": "id",
      "queryKey": "_id"
    },
    {
      "key": "email",
      "queryKey": "email"
    },
    {
      "key": "firstname",
      "queryKey": "profile.firstname"
    },
    {
      "key": "lastname",
      "queryKey": "profile.lastname"
    },
    {
      "key": "location",
      "queryKey": "profile.location"
    },
    {
      "key": "status",
      "queryKey": "profile.status"
    }
  ];

  possibleQueryProps.forEach(prop => {
    if (req.query[prop.key]) {
      query[prop.queryKey] = req.query[prop.key];
    }
  });
  console.log(query)
  User
    .find(query)
    .skip((perPage * page) - perPage)
    .limit(perPage)
    .exec(function (err, users) {
      User.countDocuments().exec(function (err, count) {
        if (err) return next(err)
        res.render('admin/users', {
          layout: "admin",
          users: users,
          query: req.query,
          active: {
            users: true
          },
          current: page,
          pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage),
          helpers,
          pagesArr: Array.from(Array(((Math.ceil(count / perPage)))).keys()).map(i => 1 + i),
          pagination: core.pagination(page, (Math.ceil(count / perPage))),
        })
      })
    })
};
```

I will be thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But pagination shows me 10pages and I don't know how to fix it. When I parse count it gives me all results not only one,

You need to count only documents that match your search criteria, so rather than `User.countDocuments()` you'll want something like `User.countDocuments(query)`.

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you.